# Getting CImg to work in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, cimg

Im attempting to get CImg (1.6.8) to work in XCode (7.2) running OSX 10.11.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

{

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
return 0;
```

}

ERRORS:

Use of undeclared identifier 'LC_COLLATE_MASK'

Unknown type name 'locale_t'; did you mean 'locale'?

Long list of errors all concerning unkown type names , undeclared identifiers and too many arguments given follows.

[ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNN0O.png)

For simplicity CImg.h and X11 are in the project folder and is an explicit search path but I have various unsolved dependencies:

Is there a general method for adding pretty much any library to integrate in Xcode ?

How and where would these dependencies be resolved?

Additional Info :

The Project settings for include dirs are recursive for the X11 folder.
Have tried it with 32bit and 64bit configs.

Comment: Don't post a picture of your code, post your code and the errors you get in the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to tell Xcode where your header files are - specifically `CImg.h`.

[image]

To do that, first click the area marked red, then the green then the blue and in the `Header Search Paths` field, enter the directory that contains the file `CImg.h`.

Normally you then have to set up the `Library Search Paths` immediately below, and the libraries to link to. But as `CImg` is a *header-only* library, there is no need in this specific case.

Finally, I inserted one line of code to avoid all the X11 stuff since OSX no longer ships with X11 and your code doesn't do any X11 stuff anyway.

```
#include <iostream>

#define cimg_display 0

#include "CImg.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It now runs fine - as you can see at the foot of the screen capture.

Hope that helps.